# What are some great examples of information dashboards integrated with core GIS capabilties via the web?

Tags: web-mapping, visualisation, integration

I am tasked with designing a GIS information dashboard (think energy consumption, capacity, or any other measurable value across a campus).  I would like to get a sense for what has been done well and what has not been done well.

For an example see the [San Diego Energy Dashboard](http://energy.ucsd.edu/campus/campusmap.php). Though this information dashboard is limited as it does not display much information on the same "page" (i.e., the map).

I am looking for dashboards with a focus on displaying a lot of information on one page with the option to drill down for more detail into other pages as needed. For non-GIS examples see [Information Dashboard at Patternry.com](http://patternry.com/p=information-dashboard/)

What are some other great examples of information dashboards integrated with core GIS capabilties via the web?

Answer (score 5):

There was a [talk at FOSS4G](http://2011.foss4g.org/sessions/building-professional-geo-analytical-dashboards-and-reports-geobiext) titled - "Building professional geo-analytical dashboards and reports with GeoBIExt." From the summary:

> It comprises:
>
> 1) GeoKettle, a spatial ETL tool targeted for
>   geo-analytical data warehousing,
>
> 2) GeoMondrian, a Spatial OLAP
>   (SOLAP) server which extends the open source Mondrian OLAP server with
>   GIS data types and functions and
>
> 3) GeoBIExt (extending the formerly
>   known SOLAPLayers project), a rich client visualization framework for
>   SOLAP data, using GeoExt/OpenLayers as the web mapping front-end. It
>   enables the creation of drillable and interactive geo-analytical
>   dashboards or more static reports, which allow the analyze of data
>   through different representations (maps, charts and cross-tabs) and
>   levels of detail in order to take more informed and hence better
>   decisions.
>
> The GeoBIExt framework is composed of a server part which
>   acts as a relay between the different data sources and the client part
>   for interactive visualisation and exploration of geo-analytical data.

A few more details [here](http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geobiext/).

I can't find any live demos, and only a [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/tbadard/spatially-enabled-open-source-bi-geobi-with-geokettle-geomondrian-solaplayers) from a few months ago. maybe someone who was at Denver can provide more details.

As an alternative to having a dashboard displaying as many graphs, maps, charts as possible have a look at http://www.giscloud.com/apps/starbucks/ - this allows a manager to type questions in natural English such as *'show starbucks within 2 miles from tube'* to analyse information.

Comment: is GeoBIExt project still alive? I couldn't find any link.